# HTML in PHP Email Template

Tags: php, email

I am using code that I have been recycling for a while now. Sorry if it is totally outdated or wrong. I copied it from a tutorial and it always worked.

My client wants to make the mail body tags bold and have the senders name in the email subject added dynamically.

```
<?php

if ($_POST["submit"]) {
    $recipient = "<!--EMAIL ADDRESS HERE-->";
    $subject = "<!--SUBJECT HERE PLUS DYNAMIC NAME-->";
    $sender = $_POST["name"];
    $senderEmail = $_POST["email"];
    $infantskidate = $_POST["infant-ski-date"];
    $infantquantity = $_POST["infant-quantity"];
    $infantdays = $_POST["infant-days"];
    $infantinsurance = $_POST["infant-insurance"];
    $childskidate = $_POST["child-ski-date"];
    $childquantity = $_POST["child-quantity"];
    $childdays = $_POST["child-days"];
    $childinsurance = $_POST["child-insurance"];
    $adultskidate = $_POST["adult-ski-date"];
    $adultquantity = $_POST["adult-quantity"];
    $adultdays = $_POST["adult-days"];
    $adultinsurance = $_POST["adult-insurance"];
    $oapskidate = $_POST["oap-ski-date"];
    $oapquantity = $_POST["oap-quantity"];
    $oapdays = $_POST["oap-days"];
    $oapinsurance = $_POST["oap-insurance"];
    $oldskidate = $_POST["old-ski-date"];
    $oldquantity = $_POST["old-quantity"];
    $olddays = $_POST["old-days"];
    $oldinsurance = $_POST["old-insurance"];
    $familyskidate = $_POST["family-ski-date"];
    $familyquantity = $_POST["family-quantity"];
    $familydays = $_POST["family-days"];
    $familyinsurance = $_POST["family-insurance"];
    $familysurname = $_POST["family-name"];
    $familyage = $_POST["family-ages"];

    $mailBody = "
        <!--MAKE THIS BOLD-->Name:<!--ENDS BOLD--> $title $sender\n
        Email: $senderEmail\n

        Infant:\n
        First Skiing Date: $infantskidate\n
        Quantity: $infantquantity\n
        No. of Days: $infantdays\n
        Insurance: $infantinsurance\n\n

        Child:\n
        First Skiing Date: $childskidate\n
        Quantity: $childquantity\n
        No. of Days: $childdays\n
        Insurance: $childinsurance\n\n

        Adult:\n
        First Skiing Date: $adultskidate\n
        Quantity: $adultquantity\n
        No. of Days: $adultdays\n
        Insurance: $adultinsurance\n\n

        65 to 74:\n
        First Skiing Date: $oapskidate\n
        Quantity: $oapquantity\n
        No. of Days: $oapdays\n
        Insurance: $oapinsurance\n\n

        75+:\n
        First Skiing Date: $oldskidate\n
        Quantity: $oldquantity\n
        No. of Days: $olddays\n
        Insurance: $oldinsurance\n\n

        Family:\n
        First Skiing Date: $familyskidate\n
        Quantity: $familyquantity\n
        No. of Days: $familydays\n
        Insurance: $familyinsurance\n
        Family Name: $familysurname\n
        Ages of Children: $familyage\n\n


    ";

    mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $sender <$senderEmail>");

    $thankYou = "<p class='thankyou'>Thank you for submitting you order. We will get back to you shortly with payment details.</p>";
}

?>
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: And? What's your question?

Comment: You don't even know what to try?

Comment: Incidentally just doing a google search using your exact title returns scores of examples of exactly how to do it.

Comment: @JonStirling - question is at top - My client wants to make the mail body tags bold, and have the senders name in the email subject added dynamically. - how to do this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use html directly in the php, then add html mail headers like so;

```
<?php
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $sender <$senderEmail>\r\n";

mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, $headers);
```

Comment: that is the correct way. see the documentation under Example #4: Sending an HTML email: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 1):

build a list of all headers in an array

```html
<?php
$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[] = "From: Sender Name <sender@domain.com>";
$headers[] = "Bcc: JJ Chong <bcc@domain2.com>";
$headers[] = "Reply-To: Recipient Name <receiver@domain3.com>";
$headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";
$headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $email, implode("\r\n", $headers));
?>
```

Comment: you mean `Content-type: text/html`, do you, @F-Nazari? And then, of course adding the html in the $mailBody.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it.

```
<b>Name:</b>
<strong>Name:</strong>
<span style="font-weight: bold;">Name:</span>
```

Comment: Novocaine mentioned you have to set correct headers in php too.

Comment: @cookney how are you testing it? Not all email programs and such, support HTML. So looking at it, you would just see the email with the html tags shown.